# Dialog's ListView doesn't call onClick after cursor contents change

Tags: android, listview, cursor, onitemclicklistener

I have a DialogFragment that displays a simple list of Tags thanks to a cursor I retrieve from the app's ContentProvider. I merge this cursor with a MatrixCursor that contains a custom record that I use to direct users to another part of the app that lets them manage the list of Tags.

Tapping on this custom record opens up another activity. From there, the user can go through the CRUD operations to manipulate Tags available for use. Afterwards, hitting the Back button takes the user back to the DialogFragment, which then refreshes the CursorLoader to display the modified Tags.

This DialogFragment implements `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` - here's the Dialog's `onItemClick()` function:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
{
    // Debug
    Log.i("DialogAssignTags", "Item clicked");
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(android.R.id.checkbox);
    int labelID = (Integer) cb.getTag();

    if(labelID == gNoTagsCursorID)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityTaggedWords.class));
    }
}
```

The first time I bring up the DialogFragment, I tap the custom record and the ActivityTaggedWords activity starts as expected.

What's weird is that, after manipulating the list of Tags and tapping Back to return to the DialogFragment, the DialogFragment's `onItemClick()` function is no longer called **only if the contents of the refreshed cursor are different than what they were before the user modified the Tags**.

For example:

> 1. Dialog is loaded and displays the following Tags:
>
>    - Tag 1
>    - Tag 2
>    - Tap here to modify tags
> 2. User taps **Tap here to modify tags** to bring up ActivityTaggedWords
> 3. In ActivityTaggedWords, the **user deletes Tag 2 and creates Tag 3**
> 4. The user taps the Back button
> 5. The app goes back to the Dialog
> 6. The Dialog refreshes the cursor and displays the following Tags:
>
>    - Tag 1
>    - Tag 3
>    - Tap here to modify tags
> 7. User needs to make additional changes to the list of Tags. They tap **Tap here to modify tags** but nothing happens

Why does the refreshed listView not call onItemClick()? Do I need to reassign `this` to the ListView's `onItemClickListener()` in onResume?

**EDIT: Here's my LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished()**

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor)
{
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        // Add a cursor that lets the user jump straight to Vocab to manage tags
        Cursor manageTagsCursor = getManageTagsCursor();
        Cursor[] cursors = { cursor, manageTagsCursor };
        Cursor finalCursor = new MergeCursor(cursors);

        gAdapter.swapCursor(finalCursor);
    }
    else
    {
        // Add a custom cursor that will direct the user to ActivityTaggedWords
        Cursor noTagsCursor = getManageTagsCursor();
        gAdapter.swapCursor(noTagsCursor);
    }
}
```

**And here's getManageTagsCursor():**

```
private MatrixCursor getManageTagsCursor()
{
    MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id", "label", "tagged"});
    cursor.addRow(new String[] { String.valueOf(gNoTagsCursorID), getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_assign_tags_no_tags), "0" });
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is not related to the adapter but to the listview, which invokes the touchEvents, you could try to invalidate 'listView.invalidateViews();', this should reinflate the views.

Comment: That didn't help at all unfortunately.

Comment: what about the solution you suggested, did it work? setting the listener again

Comment: Nope, I tried that too and the click event still won't register.

Comment: what does your loadercallbacks.onLoadFinished() look like?

Comment: I edited my question to include OnLoadFinished() and a related method.